# Unable to use toco (the compiler to optimize tf models) due to permission denied error

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I am following this tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3

I have completed the first 3 steps, but now when I try to use toco I get this permission denied error even though I am the admin.

**Using sudo has not helped.**

```
(tutorial) pal-nat186-68-98:tensorflow-for-poets-2admin$ toco --help
/Users/admin/tutorial/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:205: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/tutorial/bin/toco", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/admin/tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/python/toco_wrapper.py", line 35, in main
    os.execvp(binary, sys.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/tutorial/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 559, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/Users/admin/tutorial/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 583, in _execvpe
    exec_func(file, *argrest)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: What happens if you sudo it?

Comment: Nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. Are you on Mac?

Regardless, I found that installing `tf-nightly` in a *python2* virtual environment worked fine, while running it in a python3 virtualenv produced the same error you cite.

Comment: Yes, I am using a Mac

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on my Mac by adding executable flags to toco. Assuming you're in a terminal inside the *tensorflow-for-poets-2* folder, this would do the job:

```
chmod +x  tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/aux-bin/toco
```